# Debugging and diagnosing lock convoying problems in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, multithreading, concurrency

I am looking into performance issues of a large C#/.NET 3.5 system that exhibits performance degradation as the number of users making requests scales up to 40-50 distinct user requests per second.

The request durations increase significantly, while CPU and I/O loads appear to stay about the same. This leads me to believe we may have problem with how shared objects in our system, which are protected using c# `lock() {...}` statements may be affecting concurrent access performance. Specifically, I suspect that some degree of lock convoying is occurring on frequently used shared data that is protected by critical sections (because it it read/write).

**Does anyone have suggestions on how to actually diagnose if lock convoying is the problem .. or if lock contention of any kind is contributing to long request times?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lock convoys are hard to debug in general. Does your code path have sequential lock statements either directly or in branches?

The [Total # of Contentions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat.aspx) performance counter gives a base estimate of contention in the app.

Also break open a profiler and look. You can also write some perf counters to track down the slow parts of a code path. Also make sure that locks are only being held for as long as absolutely necessary.

Also check out the [Windows Performance Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx). I have found these to be extremely useful as you can track down lots of low level problems like abnormal amounts of context switching.

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide much insight into the diagnostics, but if you find proof to back up your assumption then you might be interested in `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim` which allows for concurrent reads, but prevents concurrent writes.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is by having a look at the [Lock and Thread performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat.aspx). Out of interesting what exactly are you locking for in your Web app? Locking in most ASP.NET  applications isn't common.